# how can make two types of views in an existing page

Tags: nsis

I try to find a solution to have a check box in the "Page components" and also when  the checkbox is checked the SectionGroup "tree mod" to be displayed and if checkbox is unchecked The SectionGroup "normal mod" to be displayed. 
All I found about checkboxs, was how to create it in custom page, 
I tried to change the code that I received from @Anders (how to create a checkbox ),  but all I did was to create me a new page in which to defend my checkbox, and there 
I could not do both display.

This is my code :

```
!include "Sections.nsh"
!include "FileFunc.nsh"
!include "LogicLib.nsh"

Page components
ComponentText""
SpaceTexts""

Var MyCheckbox


Function OnCheckChange
Pop $0
${NSD_GetState} $MyCheckbox $1
${If} $1 <> 0
    MessageBox mb_ok "Checked"
${Else}
    MessageBox mb_ok "Not checked"
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function components ; and here I have an error, because is not a custom page, but I do not want to be
;nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateCheckBox} 10u 10u 80% 12u "The checkbox text"
Pop $MyCheckbox
${NSD_OnClick} $MyCheckbox OnCheckChange

;nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd 
SectionGroup /e "tree mod"
Section /o "Communications Blockset" box_BONUS2
    ;SectionIn RO
FileWrite $9 "product=Communications Blockset$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd


Section /o "Communications Toolbox" box_BONUS
    ;SectionIn RO


FileWrite $9 "product=Communications Toolbox$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd


Section  /o "Control System Toolbox" box_MAIN
    ;SectionIn RO
FileWrite $9 "product=Control System Toolbox$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd

Function .OnSelChange
${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${box_BONUS} 
${OrIf} ${SectionIsSelected} ${box_BONUS2}
    MessageBox MB_OK "simple message box"
    !insertmacro SelectSection ${box_MAIN} 
    !insertmacro SetSectionFlag ${box_MAIN} ${SF_RO}
${Else}
    !insertmacro ClearSectionFlag ${box_MAIN} ${SF_RO}
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
SectionGroup /e "Toolbox"
Section  /o "Curve Fitting Toolbox"
    ;SectionIn RO
FileWrite $9 "product=Curve Fitting Toolbox$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd

SectionGroup /e "normal mod"
Section  /o "Curve Fitting Toolbox"
    ;SectionIn RO
FileWrite $9 "product=Curve Fitting Toolbox$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd


Section /o "Data Acquisition Toolbox"
    ;SectionIn RO
FileWrite $9 "product=Data Acquisition Toolbox$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd


Section /o "Database Toolbox"
    ;SectionIn RO
FileWrite $9 "product=Database Toolbox$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd


Section /o "Datafeed Toolbox"
    ;SectionIn RO
FileWrite $9 "product=Datafeed Toolbox$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd


Section /o "Econometrics Toolbox"
    ;SectionIn RO
FileWrite $9 "product=Econometrics Toolbox$\r$\n"
    AddSize 0
SectionEnd

SectionGroupEnd

Page instfiles
```

....

So I have two question : 
1)How can I make a checkbox in "Page components"
2)How do I show two views by pressing the Checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

NSIS was not designed to handle a checkbox on the components page. It could probably be done by creating the checkbox with the System plugin and handling the click with the [Button event plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ButtonEvent_plug-in) or the [WndSubclass plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/WndSubclass_plug-in) but no matter what you do, this is going to be a bit of a hack.

Comment: ok, thank you for this information, and now  you could help me with two views in a custom page ?

Comment: No, it is way too much work to emulate the components tree on a custom page.

Comment: @PopDaniela: Can you show any example of two view which you are actually talking about. Probably you can show/hide some controls as required. But I can only comment further if you provide some example.

Comment: As I said, I want a view which displays "tree mod" (this is a SectionGroup, as you can see in cod) and another to display  "normal mod" . The switch between the two views to be done by checking the checkbox.